# Closure compiler: variable define is undeclared

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to write a Coldfusion script that compresses JavaScript files using a recent version of Google's closure compiler. 
This program ends with two errors:

```
JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable module is undeclared at jquery-3.1.1.js line 9767 : 12
JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable define is undeclared at jquery-3.1.1.js line 9784 : 13
```

I wonder what's the magic. `module` and `define` are common JS variables; I trust Closure knows them. What setting am I missing? Is there an extern missing? Do I have to set a certain CompilerOption?

```cfm
<cfset options = createObject( "java", "com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerOptions" ).init()>
<cfset cl = createObject( "java", "com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilationLevel" )>
<cfset wl = createObject( "java", "com.google.javascript.jscomp.WarningLevel" )>
<cfset cl.SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(options)>
<cfset cl.SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.setDebugOptionsForCompilationLevel(options)>
<cfset lm = createobject( "java", "com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerOptions$LanguageMode" )>

<cfset options.setEnvironment(options.Environment.BROWSER)>

<cfset schar = createobject( "java", "java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets")>
<cfset options.setOutputCharset( schar.UTF_8 )>

<cfset wl.VERBOSE.setOptionsForWarningLevel(options)>

<cfset comp = createObject( "java", "com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler" ).init()>
<cfset clr = createObject( "java", "com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner" )>
<cfset sourceFile = createObject( "java", "com.google.javascript.jscomp.SourceFile" )>

<cfset arrInputs = createObject( "java", "java.util.ArrayList" ).init()>
<cfset arrExterns = createObject( "java", "java.util.ArrayList" ).init()>

<cfset arrInputs.add(
    sourceFile.fromCode(
        javaCast( "string", "jquery-3.1.1.js" ),
        javaCast( "string", fileRead( expandPath( "../advanced/js/jquery-3.1.1.js" ), "utf-8" ) )
    )
)>

<cfset arrExterns.addAll( clr.getBuiltinExterns(options.Environment) )>

<cfset result = comp.compile( arrExterns, arrInputs , options )>

<cfoutput>
    |#result.success#|

    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen( result.errors )#" index="i">
        err: #result.errors[i]#<br>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> module and define are common JS variables

`module` is typically an indicator of the CommonJS module system. `define` is used by the AMD module system. Neither are default JS variables or known to browsers.

jQuery is using a Universal Module Definition pattern to export the jQuery object either as a module (CommonJS or AMD as appropriate), or if none are found, as a global variable. Closure-compiler can recognize this pattern and remove the module specific parts when the `--process_common_js_modules` flag is specified.

Comment: This command line switch expressed in my Coldfusion code would be `<cfset options.setProcessCommonJSModules( javaCast( "boolean", true ) )>`